# Command Prompt doesn't work at all Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I just upgraded my computer from Windows 7 starter to 7 Ultimate using anytime upgrade. Everything went fine in the beginning but then I noticed some errors like the Windows Update window being blank, boot screen broke somehow , some programs not working etc.

I opened my command prompt and I noticed that almost everything was questions marks ( like `???? ???? ?? ??? 0x2331 ????? ??? ? ? ??? APPLICATION` ),

[image]

I didn't do anything about it and tried using the command `sfc / scannow` but it did absolutely nothing.

I tried the command help and other commands  and it gave me more question marks

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate in Arabic

When I use `dir` I get

[image]

When I use `echo %windir%` and `echo %path%` I get

[image]

`cd` and `dir` work fine but other commands do not.

Comment: What you are running is `command.com`, not `cmd.exe`. I am not surprised it doesn't run.

Comment: Nice eye, @AFH.  Kai22315: try these commands: "cd \windows" "dir" "echo %windir%" "echo %PATH"...  especially that "echo %PATH%" might be informative, I'm guessing.

Comment: Did you confirm that your language settings were retained when you upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

after 4 hours of searching I've finally found a solution . apparently , my pc had something wrong with the languages mix up , cause Arabic maybe isn't a supported language . Anyhow, what i did exactly was :

### For Windows Update window :

I Downloaded a tool called `WindowsUpdateDiagnostic` from Microsoft . And when i ran it the first time , there was one error and a couple of successful updates . Anyways , i tried and ran it again , this time with no errors , and with only 2 successful operations ( the one with the error on the first try )

### For Command Prompt "???" signs and no commands errors :

I downloaded the English Language Pack , installed it ,ran it, and that was pretty much it .

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem in the future .

Thanks , SU Community !! :D